# How do we send push notifications to thousands of devices (registration IDs) from PHP server

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging

We have set up GCM client and functionality of sending Push Notification using PHP script also works fine.
Now next task is Android APP has **thousands of registered devices**.

What is proper way to send Push Notifications to all of these devices ?

I am using PHP web server (HTTP). 
I hope my question is clear enough.

**Working Script in use for sending PUSH Notifications**

```
<?php
// please enter the api_key you received from google console
    $api_key = "proper-api-key";
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $deal = $_POST['deal'];
        $valid = $_POST['valid'];
        $address = $_POST['address'];

    // please enter the registration id of the device on which you want to send the message
    $registrationIDs= array("Few registrationIDs");
    $message = array("name" => $name, "deal" => $deal, "valid" => $valid, "address" => $address);
    $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
    $fields = array(
                'registration_ids'  => $registrationIDs,
                'data'              => array( "message" => $message ),
                );

    $headers = array(
                    'Authorization: key=' . $api_key,
                    'Content-Type: application/json');



    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

echo $result;
?>
```

Comment: Any thoughts ? I felt this is common issue... Am I misunderstanding something ?

Comment: can u pls help  me  i have written the script but failed to  send notification from server to android device ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got a link to official document.
http://developer.android.com/training/cloudsync/gcm.html#multicast

Here it clearly specifies the way to handle above said issue. So this question is answered now ! :)

> **Send Multicast Messages Efficiently**
>        One of the most useful features in GCM is support for up to 1,000 recipients for a single message. This capability makes it much easier
>   to send out important messages to your entire user base. For instance,
>   let's say you had a message that needed to be sent to 1,000,000 of
>   your users, and your server could handle sending out about 500
>   messages per second. If you send each message with only a single
>   recipient, it would take 1,000,000/500 = 2,000 seconds, or around half
>   an hour. However, attaching 1,000 recipients to each message, the
>   total time required to send a message out to 1,000,000 recipients
>   becomes (1,000,000/1,000) / 500 = 2 seconds. This is not only useful,
>   but important for timely data, such as natural disaster alerts or
>   sports scores, where a 30 minute interval might render the information
>   useless